# Change button text using another button

Tags: javascript, html

I have two buttons and I need to change the text of button1 when I click on button2.

```js
 function change() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("delUserButton")
        if (elem.value === "Disable")
            elem.value = "Enable";
        else
            elem.value = "Disable";
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit"  value="OK" onclick="change();"/>
<input  type="button" id="delUserButton<%=ud.getUserId()%>" onclick="openDelDiv(<%=ud.getUserId()%>, '<%=ud.getUserName()%>');" value="Disable" />
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle for it ? or code snippet. I guess the problem is because of the ID value, maybe try to add space between `delUserButton` and `<%=ud.getUserId()%>`

Comment: Of course it doesn't work, because you element does not have the id `delUserButton`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it won't work because you aren't using `id="delUserButton"` as an id for your second button, but you are using `id="delUserButton<%=ud.getUserId()%>"`.

So `elem` will be `null` because there's no such element with this id in the page, as `document.getElementById("delUserButton")` will return `null`.

You can see it fixed here:

```js
function change() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("delUserButton")
    if (elem.value === "Disable")
        elem.value = "Enable";
    else
        elem.value = "Disable";
}
```

```html
<input type="submit"  value="OK" onclick="change();"/>

<input  type="button" id="delUserButton" onclick="openDelDiv(<%=ud.getUserId()%>, '<%=ud.getUserName()%>');" value="Disable" />
```

Comment: the ok button is a popup menu button when i clicked it and the page is reloaded the button return to disable again !!

Comment: @MohamedNagy Sorry, and what is the problem with that?

Comment: the problem is that the button text not changed 
check out that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39891853/javascript-button-text-back-as-default-when-the-page-is-reloaded

Comment: Well it's another problem, you need to save the buttton state in this case.

Comment: can you give me some hints

Comment: @MohamedNagy Ok, your actual HTML/JavaScript code will be re-initialized when the page loads, so you need to save the button state in more persisting data, for example you can use cookies or local storage to maintain the button state after  reloading the page. Or you can use a server side technic to store it.