# Javascript : button text reverts back to default when the page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that i want to change it's text when i click on it from disable to enable , the button text is already changed but a prompt dialogue box opens when i click the disable button for asking are you sure you want to disable this user?", i have to click ok button on this dialog , but after i click on this button the page is reloaded and the button return to disable as it is .

**Here is the button :**

```
 <input  type="button" id="delUserButton<%=ud.getUserId()%>" onclick="openDelDiv(this,<%=ud.getUserId()%>, '<%=ud.getUserName()%>');" value="Disable"/>
```

**JS**

```
function openDelDiv(btnObj,userId, userName) {
    $("#userId_delete").val(userId);
    $("#userName_delete").text(userName);
    $("#delUserDiv").bPopup();
    change(btnObj);
 }


 function change(btnObj) {
    if (btnObj.value === "Disable")
        btnObj.value = "Enable";
     else
        btnObj.value = "Disable";
  }
```

Any suggestion please ?

Comment: change(btnObj) should be placed inside  bPopup() ok callback function .

Comment: Do you have a document ready event in your page? maybe you init the button every time to "disable" when you reload the page, you need to keep the change using a "cookie" for example and then check it's value and then decide what the text of the button should be depends on the cookie value.

Answer (score 0):

If you already use jQuery, use it to also bing the `'click'` event, and to retrieve the relevant data (using `data-attributes`) like so:

```js
$('.myBtn').on('click', function(){
  var $btn = $(this)
  $("#userId_delete").val($btn.data('user-id'));
  $("#userName_delete").text($btn.data('user-name'));
  var newVal = $btn.val() == 'Disable' ? 'Enable' : 'Disable';
  $btn.val(newVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="myBtn"  type="button" data-user-id="5" data-user-name="userNameHere" value="Disable"/>
```